# Firefox Recent jumplist is set to Disable but is still showing recents

Tags: firefox, pdf, jumplist

Apologies if this is the wrong StackExchange for this query--

How can I prevent Firefox from saving PDFs in Recent on the taskbar jump start? These PDFs were not even opened in Firefox or from the web, they were created on my computer and I have Adobe Acrobat Pro. Acrobat is set as my default for PDFs, and whenever I open a PDF on my local drive, it opens in Acrobat.

I have changed the Firefox settings to disable recent and frequent. I also have Firefox set to clear cookies and history on close. (I think the history and cookies clear on close is working properly.)

**Problem**
[image]

**Settings**
Windows 10, Firefox 79.0
[image]

Comment: That list does not appear to be from Firefox, but is *Windows 10* Recent Items. See https://www.howtogeek.com/236711/how-to-turn-off-recent-items-and-frequent-places-in-windows-10/

Comment: in general I like having recent items show (especially Word, Excel, etc.), I just don't want Firefox recent items to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 does not provide a way to exempt a specific application from having opened files saved in *Recent Items*; that feature has only an all-or-nothing switch. You have a few choices to control this:

- Turn *Recent Items* **off**, run *Firefox*, and turn *Recent Items* **on** afterwards. This could be done through a single batch file that does all three. The Registry setting to change is:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
  Start_TrackDocs = 0 disables tracking, 1 enables it.
- Delete the *Firefox* files from the Windows 10 *Recent Items* after **Windows** (not *Firefox*) saves them. [Microsoft states](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/settings/clear-most-recently-used-file), "To delete a specific list of most recently used files, delete the Value entry in any File Name MRU subkey." Use a cleanup program such as [PrivaZer](https://privazer.com/) or [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) to do so.
- Run *Firefox* in a virtual machine.